Recommended Language Learning Method to Write Poetry & Songs
If I am primarily interested in learning a language to write poetry and songs in it, in addition to reading poetry and listening to music, is there a recommended way to build writing skills? I imagine the grammar translation method is best because you need to be able to put sentences together in an accurate way, but they need not necessarily imitate natural speech patterns. Is there anything else I should consider?

It's not really a "language learning method" per se, but I would consider obtaining collections of traditional songs in the language you're learning. Usually these are books/CDs/methods rather intended for singing or playing on an instrument, and not for language learning. But you can also use them for learning (more of) the language once you have reached a basic skill in that language (e.g. you've reached the level where you can follow the language, and that you merely have to look up unknown words or phrases).

Just read songs and poetry. There is no method but trying first to be as fluent as you can. Try thinking about this in your own language. "grammar translation" is not a thing. Obviously, understanding the grammar of a language is the first step to then not using what is standard when writing a poem or a song.
